# Lua в PHP | Переменные

Tags: php, lua

Как сделать что-то подобное в PHP?:

```
command, name, number = text:match('/(.*) (.*) (.*)')
```

Краткое описание:

1. command, name, number это названия переменных полученных из следующих команд
2. text:match захват текста из переменной `text`
3. `(.*)` это любой текст, который будет установлен для переменных между какими-либо символами в тексте, у меня это / и пробелы. Также порядок `(.*)` и переменных определяет какая `(.*)` будет относится к какой переменной. Например переменная name будет относится ко второй `(.*)`

Результат:

Из переменной `text = "/go Jack 1"` мы получим 3 переменные: `command = "go"`, `name = "Jack"` и `number = "1"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну я уверен, что решений может быть несколько, но как самое первое что приходит на ум:

```
$text = "/go Jack 1";
preg_match('#^/(.*) (.*) (.*)$#U', $text, $match);
list($mask, $command, $name, $number) = $match;
var_dump($command, $name, $number);
```

Результат:

```
string(2) "go"
string(4) "Jack"
string(1) "1"
```